# General informations on questions

Tags: discussion, soft-question

My question is related to the enormous amount of questions that are posted here on this site.
Are these questions involving definite integrals, sequences series, limit and many more, in short all applied mathematics questions related to calculations that look pretty cumbersome  at first, are they related to some physical phenomenon or mathematical models or any other phenomenon or just there in the books for practicing.??

Comment: Should be asked on meta..

Comment: Likely a mixture of both. Hard to answer such a broad question.